# Getting Error while connection to MySQL from NodeJS

Tags: node.js, node-modules, node-mysql

```
const mysql = require("mysql");

var con = mysql.createConnection({
    host: "localhost",
    user: "root",
    password: ""
});

con.connect(function (err) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log("Connected!");
});
```

I am learning NodeJS. I am trying to connect Node with Mysql Database. Above is my code and below is output I am getting when i exectue this code. Please help me with this.

Thanks in advance.

**Error**

```
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3306
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as incomplete] (node:net:1157:16)

at Protocol.handshake (node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:51:23)
    at Connection.connect (node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:116:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (index.js:9:7)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1103:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1157:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:77:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47 {
  errno: -4078,
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '127.0.0.1',
  port: 3306,
  fatal: true
```

cannot identify. Tried to connect with mysql from command line. It succeeded, problem is only with node

Answer (score 0):

You have to mention database name here:

```
var con = mysql.createConnection({
    host: "localhost",
    user: "root",
    password: "",
    database: "You_DB_Name"
});
```

Comment: No. Adding DB name does not help.

Comment: does that change your error message?

Comment: No. Error is same

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56374530/getting-error-connect-econnrefused-127-0-0-13306 -> check this

Answer (score 0):

before code running ystart your xampp server

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33130136)